# Calculus question taking derivative to find horizontal tangent line

Tags: calculus, derivatives

How would I solve this problem?

> Find the point where the tangent line is horizontal in the following function:
>
> $$f(x)=(x-2)(x^2-x-11)$$

I computed the derivative: $\quad f'(x)=(x-2)(2x-1)+(1)(x^2-x-11)$.

But what would I do next?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Simplify $f'(x)=(x-2)(2x-1)+(1)(x^2-x-11)$

- $f'(x) = (2x^2 -5x + 2) + (x^2 - x - 11)$
- $f'(x) =  3x^2 - 6x - 9$

> And find where $f'(x) = 0$

- $3x^2 - 6x - 9 = 0 \iff x^2 - 2x - 3 = (x + 1)(x - 3) = 0$
- That's where slope is 0, hence any line tangent at that point will be horizontal: when $x = 3$ or when $x = -1$.
- So the roots (x values) of the points you need are

  - $x_1 = 3$, and
  - $x_2 = -1$.

> Then find the corresponding $y$ value in the ORIGINAL equation: $$\;f(x)=(x-2)(x^2-x-11),\;$$ to determine the two points: $(x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2)\;$ where the line tangent to $f(x)$ is horizontal.

- $y_1 = f(3) = 1 \cdot -5 = -5$
- $y_2 = f(-1) = (-3)(-9) = 27$

> So your points are $(3, -5)$ and $(-1, 27)$.

---

I've included a graph of the function $\;f(x)=(x-2)(x^2-x-11)\;$(in blue), along with the two horizontal lines tangent to the function: $\;y = -5,\;\; y = 27$ (violet and "brown", respectively) to see in a "picture" what is happening here.

[image]

Comment: I see I simplified the function to $3x^2-6x-9$ then I got $3(x-3)(x+1)$ then would I set it to zero

Comment: Exactly, solve for x, and then and we use the *original* equation to determine the y-value corresponding to each of the two x-value solutions. See the complete problem above.

Comment: I have a quick question I get how you got (3,-5) by plugging 3 into the orgional function but whenever I plug in -1 I get 33.I must be doing something wrong

Comment: Oh I see never mind. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: De nada. Your very welcome, Fernando!

Comment: You did a good job.. on a homework problem!

Answer (score 2):

You are on your way there. Consider your first derivative $$f'(x)=(x-2)(2x-1)+(1)(x^2-x-11)$$
Let's simplify this:$$f'(x)=(2x^2-5x+2)+(x^2-x-11)$$
$$f'(x)=3x^2-6x-9$$
Now, for a horizontal line, $f'(x) = 0$. So let's solve $$3x^2-6x-9 = 0$$ $$x^2-2x-3 = 0$$
$$(x-3)(x+1) = 0$$ $x = 3 $ or $x = -1$

Hence, you answer that the tangent is horizontal at 2 points, $(3, -5) $ and $(-1, 27)$

Comment: Yes it make sense then do I have to plug the x values to find the y value of the point?

Comment: yes, as edited.

Comment: gracias for your answer.