# How do I find the horizontal tangent(s) of the function $g(x) = \frac{2x^2}{x - 2}$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I need help finding a horizontal tangent with derivatives. I can partially solve it but get lost when it comes to the algebraic portion.

$$g(x)= \frac{2x^2}{x-2}$$

I eventually found the derivative and got it to this point: $$\frac{4x^2-8x-2x^2}{(x-2)^2}$$

However this is where I'm stuck. I *did* read relative horizontal tangent questions but honestly I'm clueless. This is for an optional quiz review, but if I see it explained once I'll be fine.

Comment: You see, stack exchange offers you similar questions, like this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/292919/calculus-question-taking-derivative-to-find-horizontal-tangent-line?rq=1
Try reading them

Comment: solve the equation $g'(x)=0$ to find the points where the tangent is (are) horizontal.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Hint: $4x^2-8x-2x^2=2x(x-4)=0$

Answer (score 1):

Hint : The numerator is $2x^2-8x=2x(x-4)$. You need the second derivate to decide whether you have an extremal point , or you can verify whether the sign changes and how.

Comment: Here, you have a local maximum at $x=0$ and a local minimum at $x=4$.

Answer (score 0):

To find the point(s) where the function 
$$g(x) = \frac{2x^2}{x - 2}$$
has a horizontal tangent, take the derivative, set it equal to zero, then evaluate the original function at those zero(s).

By the Quotient Rule,
\begin{align*}
g'(x) & = \frac{4x(x - 2) - 2x^2}{(x - 2)^2}\\
      & = \frac{4x^2 - 8x - 2x^2}{(x - 2)^2}\\
      & = \frac{2x^2 - 8x}{(x - 2)^2}
\end{align*}
Setting $g'(x) = 0$ yields
\begin{align*}
\frac{2x^2 - 8x}{(x - 2)^2} & = 0\\
\frac{2x(x - 4)}{(x - 2)^2} & = 0\\
2x(x - 4) & = 0\\
x(x - 4) & = 0
\end{align*}
Hence, the derivative has zeros at $x = 0$ and $x = 4$.

Substituting $x = 0$ into $g(x)$ yields $g(0) = 0$.  Thus, the function $g(x)$ has a horizontal tangent at the origin, namely the $x$-axis, which has equation $y = 0$.

Substituting $x = 4$ into $g(x)$ yields 
\begin{align*}
g(4) & = \frac{2 \cdot 4^2}{4 - 2}\\
     & = \frac{2 \cdot 16}{2}\\
     & = 16
\end{align*}
Hence, the function $g(x)$ also has a horizontal tangent at the point $(4, 16)$, namely the line $y = 16$.

In the graph below, the function is shown in blue, its vertical asymptote $x = 2$ is shown in red, its oblique asymptote $y = 2x + 4$ is shown in magenta, the horizontal asymptote $y = 16$ is shown in green, and the other horizontal asymptote, $y = 0$, is the $x$-axis.

[image: graph_of_function_with_horizontal_tangents]

Comment: Thank you so much! This answer helped me significantly!